# trajectory_filter and pluginlib syntax 1.2

Tags: ros, cturtle, pluginlib, trajectory-filters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[This tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/trajectory_filters/Tutorials/Tutorial%201) still uses pre-cturtle syntax for its plugins. Thus, when I run my trajectory_filter chain, I get

```
[ WARN] [1319409949.585461199]: Deprecation Warning: No '/' detected in FilterType, Please update to 1.2 plugin syntax. 
[ WARN] [1319409949.585612870]: Replaced NumericalDifferentiationSplineSmootherFilterJointTrajectory with NumericalDifferentiationSplineSmootherFilterJointTrajectory
```

What is the proper syntax? I'm running electric.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11645/trajectory_filter-and-pluginlib-syntax-1.2/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2011-10-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Correct syntax is defined on the [pluginlib wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pluginlib) also the [filters wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/filters) has examples.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2012-03-21**:
The filters page still has the old syntax I believe. In filter_chain.h, the above error will be printed whenever there is no / in the type. The correct syntax is hinted at on the pluginlib page, in that I think you're supposed to declare your plugin with a slash in the name (i.e. with a package)...

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2012-03-21**:
...and then use that in the scan_filter_chain parameter.